# Looking for cache daemon

Tags: linux, debian, cache, daemon

I'm looking for a daemon that I can install on my Debian server, and can be controlled through PHP (preferably with included libraries). It must have a basic key-value cache, BUT it must never ever delete any entry in the cache until I tell it to do so. Is there anything like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose [Redis](http://redis.io) should fit the requirements.  It's [packaged](http://packages.debian.org/sid/redis-server) in Debian and [has several PHP client libraries](http://redis.io/clients) of which [one appears to be packaged](http://packages.debian.org/sid/libphp-redis), though only in Sid at the moment (but I suppose it should be trivial to backport).